# Set 3 bits in the middle of the byte C# (bitwise operators)

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, operators, bit

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte value = 0;
            value = SetValue(value,5,3,7);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", value);
        }
        public static byte Mask(int l, int p)
        {
            return Convert.ToByte(~(0xff << (l)) << (p));
        }

        public static byte GetValue(int bitfield, int l, int p)
        {
            return Convert.ToByte((((bitfield) & Mask(l, p)) >> p));
        }

        public static byte SetValue(int bitfield, int l, int p, int value)
        {
            return Convert.ToByte((bitfield) = ((bitfield) & ~Mask(l, p)) | (((value) << (p)) & Mask(l, p)));
        }
    }
}
```

I get:
Exception thrown: 'System.OverflowException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

I am new to C#, when I use something very similar in C work well..

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static byte Mask(int l, int p)
{
    return Convert.ToByte(~(0xffffffff << (l)) << (p));
}

public static byte GetValue(int bitfield, int l, int p)
{
    return Convert.ToByte((((bitfield) & Mask(l, p)) >> p));
}

public static byte SetValue(int bitfield, int l, int p, int value)
{
    return Convert.ToByte((bitfield) =
                              ((bitfield) & ~Mask(l, p)) |
                              (((value) << (p)) & Mask(l, p)));
}
```

}

C# use ints for bits operations, change 0xff with 0xffffffff